# Apache/SNI: disabled or non-existent subdomain leads to other SNI subdomain being served

Tags: apache, ssl, sni

Browser is current Chrome or FF.
On the server apache 2.2ish.

I have a number of SNI sites enabled - Virtual Host *.443 etc. All separate config files. All working fine.

If I navigate to one of these "SNI" sites in a browser.
Then I disable that site on the server - e.g. `a2dissite THAT_SITE`, 
(followed by an apache reload and restart just to be sure)
Then on the browser I try to reload the original page I get:

> THAT_SITE.xx.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate
>   is not trusted because it is self-signed. The certificate is only
>   valid for ANOTHER_SITE.yy.com

where ANOTHER_SITE.yy.com is another website.

If I then accept the certificate I find myself on ANOTHER_SITE.yy.com (!)
I thought it might be a browser caching issue, but closing and reopening FF makes no difference.
It seems that the SNI def:

```
ServerName ANOTHER_SITE.yy.com
```

is "ignored"

The strange thing is that even non-existent subdomains, e.g. THAT_SITE_XX etc. are directed to the same SNI site with the same message - seems to acting as a default. Alphabetically it is the first virtual host (filename)

Answer (score 0):

The first listed virtualhost in a set of name-based virtualhosts is the default.  You can display them with apachectl/httpd/apache2ctl -S.